Clarification on Momentum and Energy Conservation in Propelling a Car by Throwing Ball
A car of mass M is initially at rest on a frictionless surface. I throw baseballs at the back of the car at a speed u and at a continuous mass rate of σ kg/s. The balls bounce elastically off the back window of the car.
I understand that momentum is conserved in this system. When I throw a ball at speed u, it collides with the car and bounces back at speed -u, resulting in a change of momentum of 2σu for the car. Thus, I can derive the car's velocity as:
$$v(t) = \frac{2σu t}{M}$$
However, I’m puzzled about the energy aspect. It seems that the car gains kinetic energy without any apparent source, which contradicts the conservation of energy. How can the car's kinetic energy increase in this scenario?
Could someone clarify how energy conservation works in this context and explain why it appears that the car gains energy "out of nowhere"?

If the car is going at the speed $u$, what happens?

car starts at zero and accelerates until speed is u, then moves at constant speed.

So how does it always bounce back at speed $u$ as the car goes faster?

Once the car reaches speed u, no baseballs collide with it anymore, and both the car and successive baseballs continue moving at the constant speed u.

Indeed. So, the momentum transfer of successive ball decreases since the relative velocity is decreasing. Consider what is happening in the center-of-mass frame.

The KE doesn’t come out of nowhere. It comes from the KE of the baseballs. The KE of the baseballs is reduced by the collision.
Elastic collisions mean that the KE of the system is constant, not that the KE of each object is constant. The total KE of the car and the ball is the same before and after, which means that the KE gained by the car is lost by the ball. The ball rebounds at a lower speed. This is how elastic collisions work.

Assume, the ball hits with velocity u and comes back with velocity -u; i.e. the energy is not reduced. But conservation of momentum implies that the car gains speed from this collision. How is this possible, what is the source of this extra energy gained by the car.

@M_Ahsan that assumption is incompatible with the collision being elastic
